# JSoup - Parsing this nested HTML unordered list

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to parse this nested HTML from a website but I just can't seen to figure out how to get the data out of the unordered list.

```
<ul class="no-bullet participants-list" data-registrations="registrants">
     <li class="participant" data-participant-id="512028" data-registrations="registrant">
         <div class="row collapse participant-info">
             <div class="large-1 small-2 columns"> 
                 <figure class="participant-avatar">
                    <a class="user-profile-link" href="THE LINK I WANT">
```

What I've tried

```
for(Element row : doc.select("ul.no-bullet participants-list")) {
         row.select("li.participant")
             .select("div.row collapse participant-info")
             .select("div.large-1 small-2 columns")
             .select("figure.participant-avatar")
             .select("a.href").text());
}
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you are looking for href attribute inside **a** tag
Your's select statement is not correct because you use space instead of dot in order to choose class

Instead of this

```
doc.select("ul.no-bullet participants-list")
```

Use this

```
doc.select("ul.no-bullet.participants-list a").first().attr("href")
```

As you see I chose first **a** tag and fetched href from this tag